# How to make a asynchronous sever request in a useReduce hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

I have set up a useReducer hook with useContext to receive a email and password for login purposes, I have created a component to fetch an authentication token from the server. I can' currently work out how to update the reducer with the returned accessToken.

> Reducer

```
    export const loginInitialState = {
      isLogin: false,
      accessToken: '',
    } as LoginInitialState
    
//this is the part that is not working
    export const loginReducer = async (
      state: LoginInitialState,
      { actionType, email, password }: LoginPayload
    ) => {
      switch (actionType) {
        case 'login':
          const data = await loginRequest(email, password)
          console.log(data)
          return {
            ...data,
          }
        case 'logout':
          return {
            ...loginInitialState,
          }
      }
    }
```

> useContext

```
export const LoginStateContext = createContext<LoginStateContextProps>(false)
export const LoginDispatchContext = createContext<LoginDispatchContextProps>(
  () => {}
)
export const AccessTokenContext = createContext<AccessTokenProps>('')

export const LoginProvider = ({
  children,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<unknown>) => {
  //@ts-ignore
  const [isLogin, dispatchLogin] = useReducer(loginReducer, loginInitialState)

  return (
    <AccessTokenContext.Provider value={isLogin.accessToken}>
      <LoginDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatchLogin}>
        <LoginStateContext.Provider value={isLogin.isLogin}>
          {children}
        </LoginStateContext.Provider>
      </LoginDispatchContext.Provider>
    </AccessTokenContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

> fetch request

```
export const loginRequest = async (email?: string, password?: string) => {
  let data: any
  await axios
    .post(`blah blah blah`, {
      emailAddress: email,
      password: password,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      data = res.data
    })
  if (data) {
    return {
      isLogin: true,
      accessToken: data.accessToken,
    }
  } else {
    return { ...loginInitialState }
  }
}
```

> dispatch point

```
const onLoginClick = () => {
    dispatchLogin({ actionType: 'login', email: email, password: password })
  }
```

I can console log the returned authentication key but I cannot get my reducer to update to the returned state.

Comment: I assume you meant "asynchronous" not "a synchronous" in the title?

Comment: Ah yes my mistake thank you

Answer (score 0):

Performing asynchronous operations in a `useReducer` isn't possible. If I'm not mistaken your state becomes a promise.

What you'd have to do is to perform that action outside and pass the data through the dispatch. So, your reducer only handles data.

Also, by abstracting your logic outside you may be interested in unit testing, therefore mocking responses for different scenarios. If it does not apply, perhaps you want to keep your API isolated, don't know, every app/team/developer has its own use case.

Last by not least, if you use `async/await` don't use `then`. It's either one or the other.

Comment: I have changed it to a useState hook and just set the state in the required destination fixed the issues thanks for the response though!